# Only paste text into html element with role="textbox"

Tags: html, css

I made an auto growing input field.
For this I used the *„Solution with span:”* solution from this CodePen: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/XWbqpzP

Basically a `span` tag with `role="textbox"`

My problem is when I copy text from websites it copies everything and when I paste it into the input field it contains all the html characters with styling.

So text has html elements such as div, p, etc... and styling like background-color, color, border...

Facebook uses the same solution with `role="presentation"` for comment writing input field for the posts. But it works fine there, it only shows text and numbers.

Is there any solution to **get rid of the additional characters**?

Here is a „case study” :)

I copied the CodePen's title from the top left corner, and paste it into the span filed. This picture is illustrates well:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFchM.jpg

And here is my code as well, if it helps to find something:

```
<span class="input__textarea input__textarea__msg" role="textbox" contenteditable></span>
```

And the css:

```
&__textarea{
    
        border-radius: 19px;
        background-color: $medium;
        padding: 6px 30px;
        font-size: 18px;
        outline: none;
        @include shadow();
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        min-height: 34px;

        max-height: 300px;
        overflow-y: scroll;

        span{
            background-color: transparent !important;
            color: $dark !important;
            line-height: 1;
            //user-select: text;
        }

        &__msg[contenteditable]:empty::before{
            content: "Send message";
            color: #757575; 
        }
```

And this is what I have in the console after I paste some content (this is not from CodePen):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hxDZ.jpg

Comment: Including the HTML and CSS code in your question would also be helpful. As opposed to just an external link.

Comment: Thanks Tanner Dolby for the suggestion! :)